# how to disable the input field after reaching 15 characters ,and also should not allow the spaces between the words using regular expression

Tags: angular, angular6

Hi i have a scenario where in my reactive form input field i need to limit or disable the field after 15 characters and also should not allow the spaces between characters ,where im using the regular expression to show  validation messages,if it exceeds 15 characters it is successfully showing validation message but its not  limiting the field after 15 characters.can anyone help me how to limit it.

```
public namePattern: string = "^([^\s]*[A-Za-z0-9]{15}[\s]{0,1})*$";

username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.patternSrv.namePattern),Validators.maxLength(15)]),
```

this is the code im using for regular expression and validation

Answer (score 3):

You can limit field length in HTML5 `input` elements natively:

```html
<input maxlength="15">
```

This also works in Angular.

Read further here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Note that this does not disable the input, just restricts the user to enter more than 15 characters - although I interpreted your question in a way that you didn't actually mean to set the `disabled` restriction

Comment: @CGundiach, I added  maxlength but i want in the regular expression itself so that i dont want to add each fields wherever i need the condition.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to use Validators to restrict or alter input. That's exactly what the `maxlength`-attribute of `input`-elements is for.

Answer (score -1):

i got the solution ,here it is
public namePattern=/^(?:\S.{0,}[a-zA-z]\S)?$/;
it will help you to not allow spaces befor and ending.if you want to have charlimit you can add maxlength="15"in custom validators and we can show validation message.hope it will heplful

Comment: Whats wrong with this , why downvote for this answer, its working fine for me